# How can I tell where exit or die is being called from within a php script

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a PHP script that hooks into Wordpress (through `wp-load.php`) to do various things. For some reason, during the script, after running `update_post_meta` (its in a loop), the script just stops. No errors, exceptions. Nothing.

I registered a shutdown function and it was called, so to me, it seems that another plugin somehow is calling `die` or `exit`. Is there a way to find out where this is being called? Perhaps a backtrace of some sort?

Comment: Did you turned on wp debug? Do you have any errors there?

Comment: On the page you're on, in Chrome, open up the inspector, and go to the Network tab. Then in the bar where the Filter bar is, select XHR (you can select ALL, but since you mentioned `die` and `exit` I'm assuming AJAX call is being made). Then when you call your script you should see all scripts being loaded, and the info on them (Headers, Preview, Response, Cookies and Timing).

Comment: No errors and no exceptions is possible, if php flag `display_errors` set to false, or `error_reporting` = 0 (or ~E_ALL). Is it?
If you think, that your script is realy stops after die() or exit() call, then you can use file content search in your text editor for `exit` or `die`

Comment: @KondukterCRO. Thanks so much... that solved my issue. I was doing `error_reporting(E_ALL)` but that was giving me nothing.

Comment: No problem. You solved it now?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. There is no way to easily and reliable trap the  die() and exit() your need to check in each file filtration modify date

Answer (score 0):

So like Sunil Kumar Sain said there is no reliable way to trap die() and exit() but you can find php errors in wp. You can turn on wp debug to true. You can find it in wp-config.php file in wordpress root directory. 
It would be great that others add more ways of catching errors. Feel free to edit this.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do this would be by using an IDE like [PHPStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) and PHP debug tools like  [Xdebug](https://xdebug.org/).